# How to refresh server code for GWT in IntelliJ (dev mode)?

Tags: java, gwt, intellij-idea

When running a gwt project in dev mode in IntelliJ, if I make any changes to the server-side code, I need to actually stop and run the app again in order for it to be updated.

Is there any other way to refresh the server-side code, so the whole app doesn't have to be restarted?

Answer (score 1):

GWT server code is real Java code, so no, you can't do that by default. However, you could use [JRebel](http://zeroturnaround.com/software/jrebel/) (commercial) to achieve what you want.